# Keyboard unresponsive on login

Tags: greeter, keyboard

I recently did a fresh installation of Hera 5.1, and since then my laptop keyboard is unresponsive on the greeter login screen. The touchpad and wireless mouse both work, but I can't type in my password. I found a way to get it to "wake up" by flipping the laptop screen around into tablet mode (convertible laptop, HP), and the keyboard will work after I flip it back around to normal. I have tried installing the drivers by using the command sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all, but that didn't fix the problem. After I get it working and log in, it works fine until I restart the laptop. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.